# Janusgraph error while tring to connect with backend

Tags: graph, janusgraph

I'm trying to run  ./bin/gremlin-server.sh ./conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml

I can see cassandra in process list but the client wont connect, i got this error all the time:

> 263  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  -
>   Configuring Gremlin Server from
>   ./conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml 400  [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager  - Configured
>   Metrics ConsoleReporter configured with report interval=180000ms 402 
>   [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager  -
>   Configured Metrics CsvReporter configured with report
>   interval=180000ms to fileName=/tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv 484 
>   [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager  -
>   Configured Metrics JmxReporter configured with domain= and agentId=
>   488  [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager  - Configured
>   Metrics Slf4jReporter configured with interval=180000ms and
>   loggerName=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.Settings$Slf4jReporterMetrics
>   1085 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  -
>   Graph [graph] configured at
>   [conf/gremlin-server/janusgraph-cassandra-es-server.properties] could
>   not be instantiated and will not be available in Gremlin Server. 
>   GraphFactory message: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph
>   implementation [class org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory]
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: GraphFactory could not instantiate this
>   Graph implementation [class org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory]    at
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.DefaultGraphManager.lambda$new$0(DefaultGraphManager.java:57)
>     at
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntrySet.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:671)
>     at
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.DefaultGraphManager.(DefaultGraphManager.java:55)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.(GremlinServer.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:354)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:78)
>     ... 13 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not
>   instantiate implementation:
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:69)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:477)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:409)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1353)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:107)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:87)
>     ... 18 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:58)
>     ... 23 more Caused by:
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary
>   failure in storage backend    at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.getCassandraPartitioner(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:219)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:198)
>     ... 28 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)    at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:185)    at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeRawConnection(CTConnectionFactory.java:110)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeObject(CTConnectionFactory.java:74)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeObject(CTConnectionFactory.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220)
>     at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.getCassandraPartitioner(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:216)
>     ... 29 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>   (Connection refused)  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:180)    ... 35
>   more 1089 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor  -
>   Initialized Gremlin thread pool.  Threads in pool named with pattern
>   gremlin-* 1877 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.ScriptEngines  - Loaded
>   gremlin-groovy ScriptEngine 2971 [main] WARN 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor  - Could
>   not initialize gremlin-groovy ScriptEngine with
>   scripts/empty-sample.groovy as script could not be evaluated -
>   javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No
>   such property: graph for class: Script1 2971 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor  -
>   Initialized GremlinExecutor and preparing GremlinScriptEngines
>   instances. 3043 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor  -
>   Initialized gremlin-groovy GremlinScriptEngine and registered metrics
>   3094 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.OpLoader  -
>   Adding the standard OpProcessor. 3095 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.OpLoader  - Adding the control
>   OpProcessor. 3099 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.OpLoader  - Adding the session
>   OpProcessor. 3549 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.OpLoader  - Adding the
>   traversal OpProcessor. 3567 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.traversal.TraversalOpProcessor 
>   - Initialized cache for TraversalOpProcessor with size 1000 and expiration time of 600000 ms 3676 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured
>   application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+gryo with
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0 3679
>   [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer 
>   - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+gryo-lite with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoLiteMessageSerializerV1d0
>   3680 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured
>   application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+gryo-stringd with
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0 3685
>   [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer 
>   - Could not instantiate configured serializer class - org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV1d0
>   - it will not be available. There is no graph named [graph] configured to be used in the useMapperFromGraph setting 3730 [main] WARN 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Could not
>   instantiate configured serializer class -
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0
>   - it will not be available. There is no graph named [graph] configured to be used in the useMapperFromGraph setting 3732 [main] WARN 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Could not
>   instantiate configured serializer class -
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0
>   - it will not be available. There is no graph named [graph] configured to be used in the useMapperFromGraph setting 3818
>   [gremlin-server-boss-1] INFO 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Gremlin Server
>   configured with worker thread pool of 1, gremlin pool of 4 and boss
>   thread pool of 1. 3818 [gremlin-server-boss-1] INFO 
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Channel started
>   at port 8182.

Comment: Did you enable thrift on cassandra ?

Comment: Could you please provide more details on which version of Apache Cassandra you are using? How did you start Cassandra? How is it configured? What operating system?

Comment: Did you check the `cassandra.log` for errors?