# Couldn't start gremlin server from JanusGraps (GraphFactory warning)

Tags: java, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

I try to start JanusGraph and I have a problem with TinkerPop gremlin server. I try both "release (0.1.1)" and "from source (0.2.0)" versions.
When I run `/bin/janusgraph.sh start` there is no error but I can't connect to gremlin with my application. 
When I start TinkerPop version downloaded from Apache site I have no problem with connection. I think that the problem is with a config file. The Apache version uses `tinkergraph-empty.properties`, the JanusGraph version: `janusgraph-cassandra-es-server.properties` (Of course, I want to use Cassandra).

A result of executing gremlin-server.sh with Cassandra config don't return any errors but returns warnings:

```
718  [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Graph [graph] configured at [conf/gremlin-server/janusgraph-cassandra-es-server.properties] could not be instantiated and will not be available in Gremlin Server.  GraphFactory message: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory]
java.lang.RuntimeException: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GraphManager.lambda$new$0(GraphManager.java:55)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntrySet.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:671)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GraphManager.<init>(GraphManager.java:53)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:83)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:110)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:344)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:78)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:69)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:477)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:409)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1353)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:107)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:87)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:58)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.getCassandraPartitioner(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:219)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.<init>(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:198)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:185)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeRawConnection(CTConnectionFactory.java:102)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeObject(CTConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeObject(CTConnectionFactory.java:35)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.getCassandraPartitioner(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:216)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:180)
    ... 30 more
```

How can I start JanusGraph with Cassanda without warnings?

Comment: This question is related to this post: [Janusgraph error while tring to connect with backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45477719/janusgraph-error-while-tring-to-connect-with-backend)

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with starting Cassandra which you one observe by running:

```
bin/nodetool enablethrift
```

as @Ashraful Islam suggested.

One need to uncomment following line(I set address to localhost) in `conf/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh` :

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: Interesting. If you get a chance to recreate the original failure scenario, it would be great if you could provide logs or other details on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/561).

Comment: I'm using Docker and I have exactly same issue.
@trojek Did you succeed?
Thanks

Comment: I did, but I don't remember exactly how. I'm not sure but probably I just reinstall the whole JanusGraph.

Answer (score 1):

**Enable Thrift server of Cassandra**

Use the below command to enable thrift in cassandra

```
nodetool enablethrift
```

Comment: Your answer was helpful but it's not the solution.

Comment: I cannot enable thrift due to configuration file. I write the solution above.